# Loading data from Cassandra at application startup

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

I am working on a java-spring boot application. I have some application's specific constant values stored in the Cassandra database and I need to hit the database for every request to fetch these constant values from the database, which is a bad practice. So I thought of fetching these values at the application startup and store it in static variables and access these variables across the application. But the problem I am facing here is, after the application startup and once the data is fetched from DB and stored in static variables, and in case if we change the values in the database, these static variables are not updating with the new values until I restart the application. Is there any best approach to update these static variables as and when we change the values in the database, without restarting the application. Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some code for what you have tried.  A "typical" solution is to run a timer loop in your application to poll the database on a regular cycle (like once per minute for example).  This will cause the application to get the latest values within 60 seconds of them changing..

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use some kind of message broker like Kafka (http://kafka.apache.org/) to publish database changes to subscribers or (without kafka) to use some kind of push notifications.

A possible setup could be something like this:

Service2 is used to change your "constants". So you should not change these values directly using cqlsh but only using this second service.
After a successfull change you could now send a http request to a "refresh"-endpoint of your regular spring-boot application. This refresh notification then can trigger an update in your application. This is basically a callback approach.

The second and more flexible way could be using a message broker like kafka.
With kafka you would still create a service which you use to change your "constants". The difference here would be that after you successfully changed your data, you would send a message to kafka. Kafka now can dispatch your message to each service which registered itself as a subscriber. Using this option you are free to add more than one subscriber in case you have more services depending on your "constants".

Personally I'm not a fan of a polling solution where you check every x seconds if a change is present.